# Windows server 2016. Configurar secuencia de apagado

Tags: windows-server

Quería saber si existe alguna manera de configurar la secuencia de apagado de un servidor windows 2016. Les cuento la situación.

Cada vez que se corta la luz, se activa la UPS que le da energía a los servidores, cuando pasa un determinado tiempo, esta manda a apagar los servidores.

Mirando el visor de eventos del servidor nos dimos cuenta que manda a apagar la base de datos por último y solo le da 10 segundos para hacerlo, luego el servidor se apaga y mata la base. Cuando se enciende el servidor, la base tiene que restaurarse y tarda mucho tiempo.

Mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma de configurar el apagado para que avise antes a la base y se cierre normal?

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Según el tipo de SAI, suele traer un software que permite para gestionar el apagado del Server y algunos de ellos permiten gestionar estos temas.

Comment: Si tu SAI no lo permite, normalmente te permiten ejecutar un .bat  por lo tanto puedes ejecutar un powershell como un .bat    http://www.gavd.net/servers/sharepointv5/spsv5_item.aspx?top=1&itm=2063   luego en el powershell, puedes apagar SQL y otros servicios. Después apagar el Server.   Echa un vistazo para crear tu .bat   https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-2017